# Printing arrays using for loop in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, for-loop

I'm trying to print the value of pointer array using for loop as usual, and I managed to print value stored in one object, but can't print the value stored in another object. My classes are defined in Predmet.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Predmet
{
public:
    int numberOfItems;
    string name;

    Predmet();
    ~Predmet();
};
```

and Plaza.h:

```
    class Plaza
{
public:
    int length;
    double x;
    double y;

    Plaza();
    ~Plaza();
};
```

My main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include "Plaza.h"
#include "Predmet.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n, m;
    int *numberOfBeaches;
    Plaza *obj1;
    Predmet *obj2;

    cout << "Enter number of beaches (N): ";
    cin >> n;

    obj1 = new Plaza[n];


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Enter length and coordinates for " << i + 1 << ". beach: " << endl;
        cin >> obj1[i].length;
        cin >> obj1[i].x >> obj1[i].y;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter number of items (M): ";
    cin >> m;

    obj2 = new Predmet[m];


    numberOfBeaches = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cout << "Enter ordinal number of beach for " << i + 1 << ". item: ";
        cin >> numberOfBeaches[i];
        cout << "Enter how much of item you have and name of the item: ";
        cin >> obj2[i].numberOfItems >> obj2[i].name;
    }

    int *p;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        p = find(numberOfBeaches, numberOfBeaches + n, i + 1);
        if (*p == i + 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                cout << i + 1 << ". " << obj1[i].x << " " << obj1[i].y << " D=" << obj1[i].length << " - predmeti: " << obj2[j].numberOfItems << " " << obj2[j].name << endl;
            }
        }

        else {
            cout << i + 1 << ". " << obj1[i].x << " " << obj1[i].y << " D=" << obj1[i].length << " - predmeti: " << endl;
        } 

    }
    delete[] obj1;
    delete[] obj2;
    delete[] numberOfBeaches;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Everything was working until this point where I add printing for obj2[i].kolicina and obj2[i].opis, I get weird looking result as a print and this exception thrown, as you can see below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance. 
EDIT:

After suggestions in the comments, I managed to fix the code (updated version above) to print it proper way, only when I have M > 1 (e.g. M = 2) I get duplicate printing of lines? How can I fix that?

Comment: You are accessing `brojPlaze` up to m, is n < m?

Comment: M can be > N, but its not neccesary. In my test case, N = 2 and M = 1.

Comment: Then it's the turn of `obj2` to be accessed up to n... Why aren't you using `vector`s, BTW?

Comment: Could you please translate into english as much of your program as possible or at least add a short explanation of it is supposed to do?

Comment: This is homework for college and I was told not to use vectors for this example. I updated code to english, check it out, class Plaza = Beach and class Predmet = Item when you translate in english. X and Y are coordinates for each beach.

Comment: @Sven B - Program seems to be running fine. I didn't see any duplicate lines. Test with different set of inputs.

Comment: Try inputing 2 items, and put them to be on beach 2 and beach 4, with 4 beaches in total

Comment: Please note that [`std::find(first, last, value)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) would return an *"Iterator to the first element satisfying the condition or last if no such element is found."*, so when you test `if (*p == i + 1) {...}` you could cause another out of bound access. See the linked page for examples of how to properly check that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
cout << i + 1 << ". " << obj1[i].x << " " << obj1[i].y << " D=" << obj1[i].duljina << " - predmeti: " << obj2[i].kolicina << " " << obj2[i].opis << endl;
```

`obj2` is being defined as having `m` elements, yet you are using `i`, which has the values `0 <= i < n`. I don't know what `m`'s relation is to `n`, but that is certainly where you should start.

Answer (score 1):

`obj2`contains `m`elements:

```
obj2 = new Predmet[m];
```

`brojPlaze` contains `n` elements:

```
brojPlaze = new int[n];
```

you are looping over all `Predmet` in `obj2`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    ...
}
```

and inside the loop, you access element `i` of brojPlaze:

```
cin >> brojPlaze[i];
```

but `i` goes from `0` to `m`, and `m` can be greater than the `n` element `brojPlaze` contains. thus, you may access an element outside of the array, which can cause a lot of undesired effects...

Comment: Look at the edited version above, now I get duplicate printed lines, how can I nest them not to be duplicated if M > 1?

Comment: @Sven B I just put random inputs in your program and did not see any duplicate lines.

Comment: Try inputing 2 items, and put them to be on beach 2 and beach 4, with 4 beaches in total